# Running sqlcmd against the WID in PowerShell remotely

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, sqlcmd, powershell-remoting

I am fighting with WSUS and trying to set up a script to manage the maintenance of SUSDB on multiple servers in our remote sites, we have servers on multiple versions and multiple OS, so it gets a bit complicated, the newer ones (post 2008R2) work with no issues, however, the Server 2008s have an issue:

I run this locally or in an interactive remote session and it works as expected, but if I nest the invoke-command to run it in a remote session as per below, it errors out with the following:

> HResult 0x2, Level 16, State 1
> Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2].
> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0 : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online..
>
> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0 : Login timeout expired

I have hunted around for days and tried all the permutations I can think of, but here's what I have:

```
$SQLPath = "C:\Users\<username>\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio\"
$SQLfile = "SUSDB-ReIndex.sql"
$WsusSvrs = ("WSUS-Site1","WSUS-Site7","WSUS-Site13","WSUS-Site14","WSUS-Site15")
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
$results = @()

Foreach ($WSUSSvr in $WSUSSvrs) {
    Try {
        $sess = New-PSSession -ComputerName $WSUSSvr -EnableNetworkAccess -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    Catch {
        continue;
    } 

    $output = Invoke-Command -Session $sess -ScriptBlock {
        If (-NOT ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")) {   
            $arguments = "& '" + $myinvocation.mycommand.definition + "'"
            Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList $arguments
            Break
        } 

        If((Get-Command SQLcmd.exe -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)-eq "") {
            $NoSQLCmd = new-object System.IO.FileNotFoundException("SQLcmd is not Installed on this machine, please install the appropriate version and try again")
            Throw $NoSQLCmd
        }

        $Output = New-Object psobject
        $OSVerStr = (Gwmi win32_operatingsystem).version.split(".")
        [single]$OS = [convert]::ToSingle(($OSVerStr[0],$OSVerStr[1] -join "."))
        $Output | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name OSVer -Value $OS

        if ($OS -gt 6.1) {
            $conStr = "\\.\pipe\Microsoft##WID\tsql\query"
        }
        Else {
            $conStr = 'np:\\.\pipe\MSSQL$MICROSOFT##SSEE\sql\query'
        }

        if(Test-Path "$using:SQLPath\$Using:SQLfile") {
            $cmd = "sqlcmd.exe -S $ConStr -i '$Using:SQLPath\$Using:SQLfile' -d 'SUSDB' -E -o 'C:\temp \$Using:WSUSSvr-reindexout.txt'"
            Invoke-Expression $cmd
            $output | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Message -Value "done"
        }
        else {
            $output | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Message -Value "Unable to find $Using:sqlfile"
        }
        $Output
    } -ArgumentList $SQLPath,$SQLfile,$WSUSSvr

    $results += $output

    if(test-path "\\$wsussvr\C$\temp\$WSUSSvr-reindexout.txt") {
        cp "\\$wsussvr\C$\temp\$WSUSSvr-reindexout.txt" "D:\wsus-reports\" -Force
    }

    If( $sess.State -eq "Opened" ) { Remove-PSSession $sess }
}

$results | ft
```

I know we should be shot of the 2008 boxes by now, but there's a niche product vendor and some budget issues in replacing the boxes.

Answer (score 0):

On line 35 I see the following

```
    Else {
        $conStr = 'np:\\.\pipe\MSSQL$MICROSOFT##SSEE\sql\query'
    }
```

Could you try running it without **np:** in front of it?

```
    Else {
        $conStr = '\\.\pipe\MSSQL$MICROSOFT##SSEE\sql\query'
    }
```

Comment: that was the original config and it made no difference, as it calls the named pipes provider anyway